# JavaScript regular expression "Nothing to repeat" error

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this error while trying to get the  tokens the code to make the lexical analysis for the Minic langauge  !

```
document.writeln("1,2 3=()9$86,7".split(/,| |=|$|/));

document.writeln("<br>");
document.writeln("int sum ( int x , int y ) { int z = x + y ; }");
document.writeln("<br>");
document.writeln("int sum ( int x , int y ) { int z = x + y ; }".split(/,|*|-|+|=|<|>|!|&|,|/));
```

I get error on the debugger for the last line Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression:  Nothing to repeat !!

Answer (score 6):

You need to escape special characters:

```
/,|\*|-|\+|=|<|>|!|&|,|/
```

[See](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Regular_expressions_1__Special_characters.html) what special characters need to be escaped:

Comment: `-` is not a special character unless used inside `[]` at a position that is not the first/last character.

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape the characters `+` and `*` since they have a special meaning in regexes. I also highly doubt that you wanted the last `|` - this adds the empty string to the matched elements and thus you get an array with one char per element.

Here's the fixed regex:

```
/\*|-|\+|=|<|>|!|&|,/
```

However, you can make the it much more readable and maybe even faster by using a character class:

```
/[-,*+=<>!&]/
```

Demo:

```
js> "int sum ( int x , int y ) { int z = x + y ; }".split(/[-,*+=<>!&]/);
[ 'int sum ( int x ',
  ' int y ) { int z ',
  ' x ',
  ' y ; }' ]
```